# How to put numbering or bullets?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I was wondering how can I put bullet number in my table.  Down below I echo list of major guidelines with sub guidelines in a loop.

ex:

```
1. major1
   a. sub1
   b. sub2
   c. sub3
2. major2
   a. sub1
   b. sub2
   c. sub3
```

something like that.

```
<table width="594" height="82" cellpadding="3" bordercolor="#999999">
    <tr>
      <td width="38" height="20" bgcolor="#333333" scope="col"><span class="style30"></span></td>
      <td width="234" bgcolor="#333333" scope="col"><div align="center" class="style31">Behavioral Guidelines</div></td>
      <td colspan="4" bgcolor="#333333" scope="col"><div align="left" class="style31">
          <div align="center">Style</div>
      </div></td>
      <td scope="col">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2)){?>
    <tr>
      <td height="24" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFCC"><div align="center" class="style7">Major</div></td>
      <td valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFCC"><div align="left"><span class="style29"><?php echo $row['majorBg'];?></span></div></td>
      <td width="17" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFCC"><div align="center"><span class="style15"><?php echo $row['msg'];?></span></div></td>
      <td width="17" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFCC"><div align="center"><span class="style15"><?php echo $row['mct'];?></span></div></td>
      <td width="17" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFCC"><div align="center"><span class="style15"><?php echo $row['mch'];?></span></div></td>
      <td width="17" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFCC"><div align="center"><span class="style15"><?php echo $row['mad'];?></span></div></td>
      <td width="194" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFCC"><span class="style24"><a href="sub.php?major_id=<? echo $row['major_id']; ?>" class="style22" >+ add sub guidelines (optional)</a></span></td>
    </tr>
    <? $sqlCommand="select * from sub_guidelines where major_id =". $row['major_id'];
    $sql1 = mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die (mysql_error()); 
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
     {?>
    <tr>
      <td height="2"><div align="center"><span class="style7">Sub</span></div></td>
      <td height="2"><div align="left"><span class="style15"><?php echo $row1['subBg'];?></span></div></td>
      <td height="2" class="style15"><div align="center"><?php echo $row1['ssg'];?></div></td>
      <td height="2" class="style15"><div align="center"><?php echo $row1['sct'];?></div></td>
      <td height="2" class="style15"><div align="center"><?php echo $row1['sch'];?></div></td>
      <td height="2" class="style15"><div align="center"><?php echo $row1['sad'];?></div></td>
      <td height="2" class="style15"><div align="left"></div></td>
      <?php } ?>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php mysql_close($con) ?>
  </table>
```

here is the result is:

```
1. major1
     a. sub1
     a. sub2
     a. sub3
1. major2
     a. sub1
     a. sub2
     a. sub3
```

They have the same numbering with major and sub.

Comment: Have you tried `<ol>`'s combined with `<ul>`'s?

Comment: If what you want are nested lists, why are you generating tables instead of `<ol>, <ul>`?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with the following HTML.  Adjust your PHP script as required to get the following output.

```
<ol>
    <li>major1
    <ol type="a">
        <li>sub1
        <li>sub2
        <li>sub3
    </ol>
    <li>major2
    <ol type="a">
        <li> sub1
        <li> sub2
        <li> sub3
    </ol>
</ol>
```

Comment: I'ved tried <ol> and <li> but they have the same number for every major guideline.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with css unordered list or ordered lists. This mite help.

http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/css/ul-list.html